# Proof that an Ideal is not a prime Ideal in the commutative Ring of Complex Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and consider the ideal $I=(x^2+1)$ of the polynomial ring $R[x]$ generated by $x^2+1$. If $R=\mathbb{C}$ prove that $I$ is not a prime ideal.

In order to prove that, I thought of proving that the quotient ring $R[x]/I$ is not an integral domain, but I am having some difficulties finding $a$ and $b$ such that $ab=0$. Is this approach correct? If so, how should try and show it?

Comment: This is a good approach. Does $x^2+1$ factor over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: yes since $x^2+1=(x-i)(x+i)=x^2-i^2$. Which means that for $x=i$ or $x=-i$ it is $0$. Does this suffice?

Comment: @Dave does this kind of proves that since $x^2+1$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{C}$ it is not a maximal ideal and thus not a prime ideal?

Comment: This works, but it's even more direct. The factorization gives you $x-i$ and $x+i$ which can be viewed as elements in $R[x]/I$ whose product is zero.

Comment: @Dave thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to prove that $R[x]/I$ is not a domain.  You can prove directly that $I$ is not prime by finding $a,b\in R[x]$ such that $ab\in I$ but neither $a$ nor $b$ are in $I$.  (Hints have already been given in the comments.)  This is essentially the same as finding zero divisors in $R[x]/I$, but it's more direct.

Generally, it's easier to prove that $R/I$ is an integral domain when you already know something about the structure of $R/I$.  If you don't know very much about $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1)$, then you may have an easier time examining the ideal $(x^2+1)$ instead.

(It's also more common to prove that an ideal $I$ *is* prime by showing that $R/I$ *is* a domain.  Proving that $I$ is *not* prime in my experience is often done directly.)